# Mysql Trigger multiple stat

Tags: mysql

I have 3 Tables : Venta , Factura, Producto .   So I'm trying to create a Trigeer that insert values on table "Factura" and udpate a value on "Producto" when inserting on Venta.  This is my first Trigger and I'dont know what I'm doing wrong, I think maybe I'm not getting the idea on how to declare variables ?.  I'll appreciate any light on this .

- I've modified the code as I did understand.  Now I'm getting a syntax error on the line were de UPDATE instruction is. By the way, the tables are:

```html
mysql> describe Producto;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Cod_Prod   | varchar(8)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Nom_Prod_P | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Precio_P   | decimal(9,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Cantidad_P | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe Venta;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_Venta     | varchar(9)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Fecha_V      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Nom_Cli_V    | varchar(24)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Rut_Cli_V    | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Dir_Cli_V    | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Nom_Prod_V   | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Precio_V     | decimal(9,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Cant_Prod_V  | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Forma_Pago_V | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe Factura;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Num_Fac      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Fecha_F      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Nom_Cli_F    | varchar(24)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Rut_Cli_F    | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Dir_Cli_F    | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Nom_Prod_F   | varchar(24)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Cant_Prod_F  | int(6)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Neto         | decimal(9,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| IVA          | decimal(9,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Total        | decimal(9,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Forma_Pago_F | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```html
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Genera_Factura_Before
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON TuOficina.Venta
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE calc_iva decimal(9,2);
   DECLARE calc_neto decimal(9,2);
   DECLARE gran_total decimal(9,2);
   DECLARE prod_descuento int(6);

SET calc_neto = new.Precio_V * new.Cant_Prod_V;
SET calc_iva = calc_neto / 0.19;
SET gran_total = calc_neto + calc_iva;
SET prod_descuento = new.Cant_Prod_V - Cantidad_P;

INSERT  INTO Factura(Fecha_F, Nom_Cli_F, Rut_Cli_F, Dir_Cli_F, Nom_Prod_F, Cant_Prod_F, Neto, IVA, Total, Forma_Pago_F) VALUES (Fecha_V, new.Nom_Cli_V, new.Rut_Cli_V, new.Dir_Cli_V, new.Nom_Prod_V, new.Cant_Prod_V, calc_neto, calc_iva, gran_total, new.Forma_Pago_V);

UPDATE Producto SET Cantidad_P = prod_descuento WHERE Nom_Prod_P = new.Nom_Prod_P; 
END$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues stand out immediately...

In MySQL numeric literal, the decimal point character must be a period (dot) not a comma.

```
  SET iva = neto / 0,19 ;
                    ^
```

In an INSERT trigger, there is no `OLD.` value for a column in the table. That is valid only in an UPDATE or DELETE trigger.

```
  SET prod_descuento = new.Cant_Prod_V - old.Cant_Prod_P;
                                         ^^^^
```

Also, beware of columns and variables with the same name, in the context of a SQL statement. When its possible a reference could be to a variable or a column, MySQL will resolve the reference to be to the column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have modified what you comment, still got another error related to mysql syntax. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting this. I realized that I had values like "iva" and "neto" using the same name of a column names.  Now I'm getting : " #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' "   . I guess is because I'm doing an INSERT and an UPDATE in the same trigger. I'll share here if I found a solution.

Comment: That error means there's already a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger defined on the table when you attempt to create a new `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the same table. Before you create a new one, you'll need to drop the existing one.

Comment: It worked! there was another BEFORE INSERT s you said.  Nevertheless I had to remove UPDATE instruction due to didn't recognize values like "Cantidad_P"  that are in another table. As on an Insert I can not use "OLD".Cantidad_P, I will have to update the table "Producto" using something else. ( can't give you "vote up" because I'm "not worthy yet" due to my reputation) .